# How to simplify my less file without repeating statement with different value?

Tags: css, styles, less

There are five less statements, and they're all the same except the value for **padding-right**.
Instead of repeating the statement five times, is there a way to simplify it into one statement?

```
h1 {
  a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"] {
    &:hover {
      background: url(../../resources/icon/external-link-alt.svg) no-repeat
        right;
      padding-right: 100px;
    }
  }
}
h3 {
  a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"] {
    &:hover {
      background: url(../../resources/icon/external-link-alt.svg) no-repeat
        right;
      padding-right: 50px;
    }
  }
}
h4 {
  a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"] {
    &:hover {
      background: url(../../resources/icon/external-link-alt.svg) no-repeat
        right;
      padding-right: 50px;
    }
  }
}
h5 {
  a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"] {
    &:hover {
      background: url(../../resources/icon/external-link-alt.svg) no-repeat
        right;
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mixins to reuse and not repeat the line of code.

> Mixins are a way of including ("mixing in") a bunch of properties from one rule-set into another rule-set.

Exemple:

```
item {
  a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"] {
    &:hover {
      background: 
        url(../../resources/icon/external-link-alt.svg)
        no-repeat 
        right;
    }
  }
}
```

And we want to use these properties inside other rule-sets. Well, we just have to drop in the name of the class where we want the properties, like so:

```
h1 { 
  item();
  padding-right: 100px;
}

h3 { 
  item();
  padding-right: 75px;
}

h4 { 
  item();
  padding-right: 50px;
}

h5 { 
  item();
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

This is very helpful if you want to change something in the future, as you only need to modify the mixins in one place .

Comment: is there a way that i don't pass "padding-right" a value from a variable based on the heading size?

Comment: Yes, there is a form with JavaScript, there is a repository of mine that I use this strategy. [Look here](https://github.com/fariasmateuss/product)